# How to pass a parameter ID to view, and then take it?

Tags: java, android

I have apps from this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1928230 - PetTracker 2.0
I'am learning Android and i would like now add for this simply CRUD. Now i would like add parameter ID to layout:

This is single item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutHeader"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_PetName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_PetType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i must add ID from my DB SQLite, but when and how?

Adapter for this item:

```
    ListAdapter adapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.pet_item,
            mCursor,
            new String[]
            {
                Pets.PET_NAME, PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME },
            new int[]
            {
                R.id.TextView_PetName, R.id.TextView_PetType });

    ListView av = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.petList);
    av.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Next i would like get my ID (database, not android:id) from single item on click:

```
    av.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(
            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     // ???
    }
    });
```

Is this possible in Android? If yes, how?

Comment: 1. Add a TextView to display the ID. 2. Add the appropriate mapping to your adapter.

Comment: "Next i would like get my ID (database, not android:id) from single item on click:" Did you read the code that you pasted here? Did you see the parameter named `id`?